# How to test method that only print out message

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have method that print winner in the class Game:

```
public void getWinner(String winner){

   System.out.println("WINNER IS " + winner);

}
```

How can I test this method so far I have:

```
Game gm = new Game(); // it is declared in @before

@test

public void test(){

  ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputSystea();

  System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));

  gm.getWinner(Bob);

  assertEquals("WINNER IS Bob",outContent.toString());

}
```

I have an error message that say

```
org.unit.ComparisonFailuter expected:<WINNER IS Bob[]> but was: <WINNER IS Bob[
]>
```

Well could you please give me a tip on how to test getWinner method

Comment: `println` adds a new line character.

Comment: You need to show more code.. What is `Bob`? Also, fix the typos in your code.

Comment: Note also that `ByteArrayOutputStream#toString()` is deprecated.

Comment: Instead of doing that, you'd better redesign the code and make the method return the string, or take a Writer as argument.

Comment: Really, you shouldn't be testing side effects.

Comment: Alas, sometimes testing side effects is necessary for functional tests, since in the end the main output of a program is a "side effect". On the other hand, this function's so trivial that I would argue it isn't worth testing.

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream.toString() is not deprecated. Testing sideeffects is sometimes nescessary (and possible in this case).

Answer (score 2):

omg don't do it! you don't have to test the `println` method. guys from sun and oracle have already done that - you can be sure it works. all you have to test is that you pass the right string to to that method. so refactor your code and create a function that return the desired string and test only that method by simple string comparison

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29):

```
public void println(String x)

Prints a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().
```

So when you print the line in the method, there's a line separator after it which is [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29) as so:

`The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').`

So you can either add a hardcoded line separator to your expected output, or you could use the following code to get the separator for the current system and append that.:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Answer (score 0):

A mockist approach:

```
@Test
public void testGetWinner()
    {
    // setup: sut
    Game game = new Game();
    PrintStream mockPrintStream = EasyMock.createMock(PrintStream.class);
    System.setOut(mockPrintStream);

    // setup: data
    String theWinnerIs = "Bob";

    // setup: expectations
    System.out.println("WINNER IS " + theWinnerIs);

    // exercise
    EasyMock.replay(mockPrintStream);
    game.getWinner(theWinnerIs);

    // verify
    EasyMock.verify(mockPrintStream);
    }
```

Pro: You don't need to care what `System.out.println()` does, in fact if the implementation changes your test will still pass.

Answer (score -2):

I think you try to compare to strings with `==` when you should use `.equals()`. The strings are stored i a constant pool, but in this case you read a string from somewhere else, which not nescessarily goes into the constant pool.

Try

```
assertTrue(outContent.toString().equals("WINNER IS Bob"));
```

or whatever your testing library calls it.

which looks for the characters in the String instead of the memory address ("ref") of the String.

Comment: assertEquals() does what its name tells: it compares its two arguments with equals. Using assert() is really not a good advice to give.

Comment: Yes, but you do not want to test equality of the string object references, but through the .equals-method. Given the facts in the question this seems to be the error. assert is the right thing, edited!

Comment: Re-read my comment. assertEquals() uses equals. not ==. And, as the comments have said from the beginning, before you even typed your answerand as the error message shows, the problem is the newline character that is added by println(). It has nothing to do with == vs. equals. assert() is NOT the right tool. assert is a low-level mechanism that is usually disabled. It isn't part of the unit-testing framework.